# How do I get the base object from within a plugin?

Tags: magento2, plugin, magento2.3.3

How do I get the object that my plugin is attached to from within an `after` plugin?  I thought it would be the `$subject` parameter, but that doesn't seem to be it.

My plugin is defined like this

**di.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable">
        <plugin name="MyCompany_Configurable" type="MyCompany\ConfigurableProduct\Plugin\Configurable" sortOrder="10" disabled="false"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**Configurable.php**

```
public function afterGetJsonConfig($subject, $result)
{
    // ...
}
```

I assumed that `$subject` should be an instance of `Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable`, but when the plugin runs, `$subject` is actually `Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Configurable\Interceptor`.

The reason that this matters is because I want to call `getAttributesForCollection` on the object that the plugin is attached to.  However, if I call `$subject.getAttributesForCollection(...)` it returns null.  When `getAttributesForCollection(...)` is called in the base class (`Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable`), it returns an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method getAttributeForCollection is only available in the class Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable

You can check the original getJsonConfig Method on how the attribute data in the JSON is implemented.